# HTML empty DIVs not well rendered by browsers

Tags: html, browser, tags, xhtml

I receive XHTML documents that sometimes contain the following code:

```
<div align="center" />
```

My problem is that browsers (Firefox 38.0.1, Chrome 43.0.2357.65) display this code as an opening `<DIV>` tag and not, as I expected, as an empty div (`<DIV></DIV>`). The rest of the document is, therefore, completely messed up.

Is it a browser bug or an XHTML feature? The code looks perfectly legal (although meaningless, but I am not the producer) and is accepted by XML parsers (Perl XML::LibXML, https://validator.w3.org/check).

You can check what it looks like in your browser with the following XHTML code (validated by https://validator.w3.org). The last DIV is displayed as bordered text, which it shouldn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; color: red;">
      <div />
      <div>Should be red and inside the border.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Should be outside the border and not red.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is the same with an XHTML Strict Doctype.

Comment: Ah, a real XHTML question. That doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, don't do this!

In HTML, a `<div>` tag is a start tag, no matter if it contains a `/` or not. The `/` is viewed as an error and is discarded.

In XHTML, this would be a complete `div`, yes. However, XHTML files are only XHTML files if they are served up with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type.
It does not matter what the contents of the file are; if the file is served up with a MIME type of `text/html`, it's a HTML file as far as the browser is concerned.

Plain files with a file name extension of `.xhtml` are treated as XHTML, `.html` is treated as HTML. If you are using systems like PHP or ASP.NET etc, you will need to send the appropriate HTTP header for the MIME type, otherwise it will use the default (usually text/html).

Comment: +1, but I'd drop the first line. The OP is receiving these XHTML files, so just needs to know how to deal with them properly.

Comment: Hm, but the answer still is, don't do this. Even it the files were real XML files, constructs like this are still against the rules for XHTML, even if they are well-formed XML (and even if they would be displayed correctly in all browsers). So I'm not sure how else to word this.

Comment: I mean, what would be the solution? Change the files to a XHTML file type? Change the content to `<div></div>`?

Comment: No, the construct is not against XHTML rules. The solutions are either serve the file using the `application/xhtml+xml` mime type, or parse the file with an XML parser to a DOM and then serialise that out as (`text/html`) HTML.

Comment: @Alohci but the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3) says "All elements other than those declared in the DTD as EMPTY must have an end tag. Elements that are declared in the DTD as EMPTY can have an end tag or can use empty element shorthand".

Comment: You are right, I forgot to check the MIME type...

I receive these files from FTP and insert their content in my own XHTML documents, which I used to send to the browser... with a `text/html` MIME type! 

Changing it to `application/xhtml+xml` solved my problem (and forced me to fix everything that was not true XHTML in my own code). That's much better than removing the empty DIVs, since I might receive other XHTML-specific stuff in the future.

Thank you!

Comment: @MrLister - You link to a point in section 4. Section 4 starts "This section is informative." That is, they are not rules, just guidance.

Comment: Furthermore, section 4.3 applies to elements which have some content. As for elements with no content, the [Element Minimization and Empty Element Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3) section (in the HTML Compatibility Guidelines appendix) says that the minimined form `<p />` should be avoided *by authors who wish their XHTML documents to render on existing HTML user agents*. Therefore `<p />` is XHTML-legal (if it was not the case, they would say that *everybody* must avoid it).

Comment: OK, OK. (Man, I'm glad I posted this in the comments and not in the answer itself.) But @surlesmarches, "empty elements" in SGML lingo means elements that are _defined_ to have no content, not just elements that happen to have no content. What HTML5 calls "void elements".

Comment: You solved my problem and I learned things about XHTML; that's the most important...